# Como executar uma requisição síncrona em um looping

Tags: javascript, loop, fetch

No exemplo abaixo

```
let arr = [
  { 3 : 'teste' },
  { 5 : 'teste' },
  { 1 : 'teste' },
  { 2 : 'teste' },
  { 0 : 'teste' },
  { 4 : 'teste' }
];

arr = arr.sort( ( a , b ) => { return Object.keys(b)[0] - Object.keys(a)[0] } )

console.log( arr )

/*
[ { '5': 'teste' },
  { '4': 'teste' },
  { '3': 'teste' },
  { '2': 'teste' },
  { '1': 'teste' },
  { '0': 'teste' } ]
*/

arr.forEach( ( el, key ) => {

  fetch( this.url + el[ Object.keys(el)[0] ], {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
      }
  }).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
  }).then((result) => {

  ...

} )
```

Eu ordeno um array em ordem decrescente baseado na `key` de cada objeto dentro dele, pois quando executo o `looping`, preciso executar a requisição do maior para o menor.

O problema é que o `fetch` é assíncrono ou seja, essa ordem não vai funcionar pois ele executa as requisições em paralelo, e qual receber o resultado primeiro vai entrar no `then` ou no `catch`

Preciso que o `forEach` espere a requisição terminar para ir para o próximo item, é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) para executar todas as requisições assíncronas e, quando todos os resultados forem recebidos, trabalhar com eles na mesma ordem em que foram chamados.

```
Promise.all([req_1, req_2, req.3]).then(reqs => {
    console.log(reqs) // [result_1, result_2, result_3]
})
```

Seu código ficaria parecido com este:

```js
let arr = [
  { 3 : 'teste' },
  { 5 : 'teste' },
  { 1 : 'teste' },
  { 2 : 'teste' },
  { 0 : 'teste' },
  { 4 : 'teste' }
];

arr = arr.sort(( a , b ) => Object.keys(b)[0] - Object.keys(a)[0])

const URL = "https://httpbin.org/anything"
let requests = arr.map(obj => fetch(URL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(obj)
}))

Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => {
    responses.forEach(response => {
      response.json().then(json => console.log(json.data))
    })
  })
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @fernandosavio, a solução quase resolveu meu problema, no promisse.all estão entrando muitos resultados, e quando ele faz o looping as vezes eles entram no then fora ordem, o que faz sentido pois mesmo que o then não esteja esperando uma requisição, ainda sim há atrasos de processamento creio eu, o que acaba quebrando o ciclo, você saberia como resolver isso?

Comment: isso só acontece no mozilla na verdade

Comment: Estranho, na [documentação da MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Return_value) especifica que o array passado para a função é na ordem do array de Promises.